# Identify Opamp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier

I try to get a detailed understanding of the following circuit that is from [here](http://www.wa4dsy.com/robot/radar-motion-detector) and is part of a radar motion detection circuit.

[image]

Is my assumption correct that the first LMC6484 is a frequency dependant inverting amplifier (with C1) and the diode D2 is limiting the negative drop of the feedback to 0.7V? What's the purpose of this diode?

Comment: A data sheet for the HB100 is required to understand its output impedance.

Comment: The diode is making the circuit a half wave rectifier. It's used with an opamp because a diode is 700mV drop, whereas the input is only 50mV.  To me this looks like a signal strength indicator, which is also confirmed by the note on the output.

Comment: If the output impedance of HB100 is low, then C1 is just AC coupling. If there is any impedance of merit, then as @Andyaka mentions, we'd need that to know anything about frequency.

Comment: Looks like a differentiator to me. The faster the input signal drops, the higher will be the output at pin 1.

Comment: I don't have information about the sensor's output impedance, neither the HB100 datasheet nor the one of the IPM-365 that I use has it specified.